# What exactly is a reference variable in Java? How does it differ from other variables?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I have been studying Inheritance in Java and the writer makes the statement "it is the type of object being referred to (not the type of reference variable) that determines which version of an overridden method will be executed." 
This statement is awfully confusing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What the book is referring to is *polymorphism*, more specifically through *dynamic dispatch*.

In a nutshell, imagine the following classes:

```
public class Person {

    public Person() {
    }

    public void introduceYourself() {
    } 

}

public class Texan extends Person {

    public Texan() {
    }

    public void introduceYourself() {
        System.out.printLn("Howdy y'all!");
    } 

}

public class NewYorker extends Person {

    public NewYorker() {
    }

    public void introduceYourself() {
        System.out.printLn("Yo. You got a problem with that?");
    } 

}
```

Now, let's create a reference variable of type `Person`.

```
Person myBFF;
```

Let's instantiate him

```
myBFF = new NewYorker();
```

Let's ask him to introduce himself

```
myBFF.introduceYourself();
```

This prints:

> Yo. You got a problem with that?

Now, let's change your BFF to a Texan.

```
myBFF = new Texan();
```

Let's call that same line again and ask our BFF to introduce himself.

```
myBFF.introduceYourself();
```

This prints:

> Howdy y'all!

In each case, the reference variable you were using was of type *Person*. The *instance* of the variable, in each case, was *NewYorker* and *Texan* respectively. *That* instance type determines which verson of *introduceYourself()* is called.

Comment: You have a real knack for explaining! Really grateful but I do have one question; is the reference variable always of the type superclass no matter how many generations of sub classes? Eg. If I extended Texan to SouthernTexan, would that reference variable still be of type   Person?

Comment: Yes, but you can declare a reference variable to be of a type closer to the instance type. For example, you could do `Texan bob = new SouthernTexan();` or `SouthernTexan sue = new SouthernTexan();`, but you could *not* do `NewYorker clyde = new SouthernTexan();`, nor could you do `SouthernTexan henry = new Person();`.

Answer (score 4):

A reference variable is the type you specify on the left hand side (a variable that holds a reference type). What the author is referring to is when the right hand side then differs. Consider

```
Object a = new Foo(); 
System.out.println(a.toString());
```

if `Foo` overrides the `Object.toString()` (that is, if `Foo` provides a `public String toString()`) method **then** it is `Foo`'s `toString` that is invoked (not `Object`'s). See also [Overriding and Hiding Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) in the Java tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

A reference variable looks like this :

```
Coordinate cords; //Cords is the ref. var
```

Inside of *that* reference variable is an address inside of your computer's RAM which stores the attributes of that object. Since we did not instantiate (actually make an object of) the address of the aforementioned cords object is `null`

Reference variables hold addresses to reserved parts of memory.

```
cords = new Coordinate(0.0,0.0,0.0);
```

Now inside of the RAM of the computer is a reserved space that holds three floating type variables. Upon instantiation, a reference variable holds the address. So what can we do with addresses in Java?

Nothing of use. Java memory address are useless, and you can not see them(Though they look something like 0xFFFFFFF)

For a visual representation click [here](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/images/ReferenceIsAPointer.png)

Answer (score 1):

Reference variable is a term to indicate/explain that a variable
is only referring to a type and yet not instantiated.
Also after instantiation it's type will be something that would depend on how or by which class a reference variable will be instantiated.

Say from the above example by Robert Columbia saying

```
   Person myBFF;
```

Or by the example of Brenann

```
   Coordinate cords; //Cords is the ref. var
```

In both these cases myBFF and cords **are only referring** to Person or Coordinate classes respectively. Note that they are **not instantiated yet!**