# How does the node in the linked list points to the next node when there is no pointer in java?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I read in a book that a node in `linked list` points to the `next node` and so on. So how does nodes get the address of  the next node?

(is it because we pass the reference variable of the previous node to the newly created node through the constructor argument?)

Comment: A reference is Java is basically a pointer.  References do all the same things pointers do, essentially.

Comment: See [I'm having trouble understanding how object references work in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56785593/im-having-trouble-understanding-how-object-references-work-in-java) and [What exactly is a reference variable in Java? How does it differ from other variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47361971/what-exactly-is-a-reference-variable-in-java-how-does-it-differ-from-other-vari)